# Why is a limit of an integer function $f(x)$ also integer?

Tags: calculus

Why is a limit of an **integer** function $f(x)$ also integer? For example, a function that's defined on interval $[a, \infty)$ and the limit is $L$

Answer (score 1):

Do you mean $f:[a,\infty)\to\Bbb Z$ as integer function? In $\Bbb R$, the set $\Bbb Z$ consists only of isolated points.

Answer (score 0):

If the limit of $F$ is $L$, then a direct consequence is that for $x$ big enough, $F$ will be as close to its limit as you want, which is to say that $\epsilon=|f(x)-L|$ becomes as small as you want.

Hint : what happens if $\epsilon<\min(L-\lfloor L\rfloor,\lfloor L\rfloor+1-L)$ ?